# Retrieving particular object value after unmarshaling the XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I am trying to retrieve particular object value to print in my console, I was able to print the entire XML. But I just need to get only few particular node values which I would like to save in my database.

Comment: If, as you say, you were able to unmarshal an XML file, which should mean you now have an object, representing this XML file, printing some of the properties of the object, would be as easy as just `System.out.println("Some value of my object: " + myObject.getSomeValue())`. Read this post: [Mapping XML to an object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16755094/814702). There is a link to the "JAXB hello world example", which is short and easy to understand. Hope this helps.